# jQuery - Getting Image url/link/path to upload image on imgur from client side

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

I am trying to upload image that is selected by client via file browser to imgur.com but problem is that how can I get the url to upload image to imgur because we need url to upload image.

My code works well with Image already on net for example http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png

Here is css code -

```
<input id="filebrow" type="file" accept="image/*" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Here is jQuery code that is triggered via button -

```
$('#filebrow').change(function(event) {
    var clientId = "CLIENT ID HERE";
    var imgUrl = "";//HOW to get url of selected file here??           
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {image: imgUrl},
    success: fdone,
    error: function(){alert("failed")},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
    }
});
});

function fdone(dataa)//called on ajax success 
{
     alert("Link :"+dataa.data.link);
}
```

If in ***var imgUrl*** I enter a image url of already uploaded image it works fine, but I want to upload image that user selects via file browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing the answer of websky I did some research and found the answer.
He missed one line which seprates url.
So here is simplified code which I used and that worked : -

```
$('#filebrow').change(function() {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
   //this next line separates url from data
   var iurl = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",") + 1, e.target.result.length);
   var clientId = "CLIENT ID HERE";               
   $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {
    'image': iurl,
    'type': 'base64'
    },
    success: fdone,//calling function which displays url
    error: function(){alert("failed")},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
    }
});
};
 reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Displaying URL of image after upload -

```
function fdone(data) //this function is called on success from ajax
{
   alert(data.data.link);     
}
```

Thanks to websky his answer helped me in finding solution.

Answer (score 2):

I say:

1. you need to read the source

for example, use new FileReader() (JS)

2. Add a source to a variable imgUrl

my vision :) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                var sizef = document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0].size;
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                document.getElementById("uploadImageValue").value = oFREvent.target.result; 
            };
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#viewSource').click(function ()
            {
                var imgUrl = $('#uploadImageValue').val();
                alert(imgUrl);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadImageValue" name="uploadImageValue" value="" />
            <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><br />
            <input id="uploadImage" style="width:120px" type="file" size="10" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif, image/png" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="viewSource">Source file</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know how to preview but I don't wanna preview I wanna upload to imgur. I have given the code of how do I upload images to imgur but I need url of image for that but how do i url of image to upload from this?

Answer (score 0):

After reading websky's answer. I can upload to Imgur successfully!. Thank You :) so i would like to sum it up for anyone who have problem uploading image to Imgur

1. You need to prepare base64 encoded image (please read websky's answer to see how)
2. Get only the data part from base64 using "substr" function
3. Prepare your ajax and posting to Imgur like this

```html
var base64 = base64.substr(base64.indexOf(",") + 1, base64.length);
$.ajax({ 
      url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {
        'image': base64
      },
      beforeSend:function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
      },
      success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
      }
})
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use CURL to upload images with imgur api. Which will return you with JS ENCODED information. You can easily retrieve the 
URL from there.

Comment: cURL with Ajax?  how would that go?

Comment: No, I recommend not to use jquery but CURL